# I want to select and cont last week duplicate value from database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select and cont last week duplicate value from database and print in array I use some code but it's not working well. Here is my code.

my date column name is date_num

it Display name and cont its duplicate but didn't filter it by date.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT country, COUNT(*) FROM grabber GROUP BY country ;");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['country'];
    echo $row['COUNT(*)']; 
}
```

Comment: My code is here $result = mysql_query("SELECT country, COUNT( * )  FROM grabber GROUP BY country ;");  
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))  
{    
echo $row['country'];  
echo $row['COUNT(*)'];
}

Comment: You should edit that into your question.

Comment: I can't make any sense of this.

Comment: Please read the [faq] about how to ask the right questions to get the help you need.  With confusing questions, it is hard for the community to assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can assign `count()` a name using `AS` so you can call it later

```
SELECT country, COUNT( * ) AS total FROM grabber GROUP BY country
```

So now you can print

```
echo $row['total'];
```

Then I would like you to remember that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated so i would advise you to switch to [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 0):

I think it should add `date_num` into `group by` clause